# angularjs poller notifyCallback status code

Tags: angularjs

is there any way we can access the response status? in the notifyCallback, It seems to me that it does not care about the status.

```
(function tick() {
  resource[action](params, function (data) {                                
    deferred.notify(data);
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you mean like attaching a state to data? like data.success = true

Comment: Yes, For every server response it only goes into notifyCallback block regardless of the status. I have checked the data and all it has is promise and resolved. What I need is to check if status is 200 I should redirect the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I have learnt it is impossible to have access to data returned by the server if I use ng-resource, since ng-resource does not give you access to header, status nor data. What I did was to rewrite my poller service. this works well

registerController

```
poller.polling(generatePollerID(), resourceUrl, 1000, successCallBack, failureCallBack, 15);

var successCallBack = function (data, status, headers) {

if(status == 202 && data == "") {

// your success code here
}
};

var failureCallBack = function (data, status, headers) {


// your failure code here
}




pollerService 

var myApp = angular.module('poller', []);

myApp.factory('poller', function($http){

var pollList = {};
return {
startPolling: function(pollerName, url, pollingTime,  successCallBack, failureCallBack,
timeFrame) {

if (!pollList[pollerName]) {

counter = 0;

var poller = function() {

counter++;

$http.get(url).success(function (data, status, headers) {

if((status == "200") || (counter == timeFrame && status == "202") ) {

clearInterval(polls[name]);
delete pollList[pollerName];
counter = 0;

successCallBack(data, status, headers);
}
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

clearInterval(pollList[pollerName]);
delete pollList[pollerName];
counter = 0;

failureCallBack(data, status, headers);
});
};
poller();
pollList[pollerName] = setInterval(poller, pollingTime);
}
}
};
});
```